# South does not register ID column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-south, database-migration

I converted an existing Django app to use South. I needed to add an ID column to one of the models, so I added `id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` to the model. But when I run:

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

I get:

```
Nothing seems to have changed.
```

And when I subsequently try to migrate the app, it says there's nothing to migrate. So I went into psql and inserted the column directly with SQL. But how do I sync my model with the database at this point?

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

says that I need to migrate my app, but nothing happens when I `python manage.py migrate myapp`.

Comment: Have you tried `--initial` instead of `--auto`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django implicitly creates the `id` column, with [this exact definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields):

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

So, in fact, nothing has changed!

The message you get when you do `syncdb` is just a reminder that your app *uses* migrations; it does not mean that there are currently unapplied migrations.

Comment: That explains it. Thank you!